# Trying to use CSS to locate on a row in a table

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Im trying to find a way of using CSS to locate on a specific cell in a table in order to verify the row exists and verify the row's cells content.

I was able to use the Selenium IDE to create a query like

```
css=td:contains('BAD')
```

The 'BAD' is a unique client code so locating on this verifies the row exists for the client.

However, when I export this to C#/nunit/Webdriver, the test does not work.

Is there an alternative method using CSS I could use?

The html for some of the table tata is as follows;

```
 <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="client in clients">
    <td class="text-left ng-binding">Bart's Ad</td>
     <td class="text-left ng-binding">BAD</td>
     <td class="text-left">
     <span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in client.SecurityGroups">
     <a class="label label-info ng-binding" href="#/SecurityGroup/MemberClients   /Assistants"> Assistants </a>
     </span>
     <span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in client.SecurityGroups">
     <a class="label label-info ng-binding" href="#/SecurityGroup/MemberClients/Managers"> Managers </a>
     </span>
```

[edit]
I have also used;

```
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)
```

Which will find my cell, but its not as nice as verifying the row for the client exists using a query that includes a client specific attribute.

Best regards
AlmightyJoygasm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath instead:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(), 'BAD')]"));
```

For what you're trying to match, this xpath should work:

```
By.XPath("//td[contains(text(), 'Smith')][1]")
```

Your xpath finds the first `<td>`, then tries to match the text `Smith`.

What you want to do is find the `<td>` elements that contains the text `Smith`, then return the first instance of that.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the input.  Is there a way I can chain this to specify a column also, just realised that the user could have a name of Smith, and then have a client code of Smith, So I want to be able to specify column 1 and then the text Smith, so something like By.XPath("//td[1][contains(text(), 'Smith')] - but this doesnt work

Comment: Thanks again - For some reason I got my own edit working, //td[1][text()='Smith'], which will find Smith on the first column, then td[2][text()='Smith'], which will find smith on my second column.  Not sure why id didnt work before, probs a typo in firefinder.  I also tried your edit, which I got working and will come in handy for a search too.  Cheers